# Как сделать единую точку входа

Tags: php, html

Возможно данный вопрос уже решался,но я решил его задать здесь. У меня есть два файла sql.php и add.php. Как мне сделать,чтобы у меня была единая точка входа?например через файл index.php или html,чтобы я зашел через этот файл и у меня не было проблем с добавлением пользователей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

в index.php

```
<?php

//....Здесь какой-то Ваш код

//.... Здесь Вам понадобился файл sql.php

require_once('sql.php');

//.... Здесь Вам понадобился файл add.php

require_once('add.php');

?>
```

Работа всегда начинается с файла index.php в котором Вы уже подключаете sql.php и add.php (3 файла получается)

Comment: А как работает htaccess,если я его не подключаю ни в каком файле?Как я понимаю мне надо requir_once прописать на него?

Comment: @user328894 никуда его не надо прописывать =) , это не php файл, это настройки сервера. положите файл с именем .htaccess в корень и скопируйте туда настройки

Comment: Огромное спасибо. А еще один вопрос спрошу у вас,как ответил человек снизу. Если создать index.php и туда прописать require_once на файл sql.php. Это тоже рабочий вариант?

Comment: @user328894 Нет , так если Вы перейдёте по адресу http://mysite.com Вы попадёте в файл index.php, в котором подключается файл sql.php. Но если Вы руками перейдёте по http://mysite.com/sql.php. То Вы попадёте только в файл sql.php, что наверняка вызывет ошибки, т.к. Код из файла index.php не отработал, и вообще не подключился. Если же Вы указываете в .htaccess перенаправление на index.php (конкретно эта строка RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]) , то что бы вы не написали в адресной строке, Вас всегда будет кидать на index.php. И это и будет единая точка входа.

Comment: Спасибо,теперь это понял. Но вопрос к тому,что получается у меня два файла sql и add. Мне нужно создать index.php и что туда добавить?

Comment: @user328894 в index.php они должны подключатся в нужном Вам месте.

Comment: А вот это не понял. Мне в конечном итоге надо файл sql переименовать на index? Или создать index и прописать require?

Comment: @user328894  я переправил ответ. Если ответ Вас устраивает поставьте напротив него галочку.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо. Просто из за того,что у меня немного криво сделано,у меня в index php по итогу только require остается,больше кода там нет. И переходить я должен по адресу mysite.com,верно?а не mysite.com/index.php или sql.php

Comment: @user328894 Это нормально что в index.php  у Вас одни require() , так полно сайтов сделано =) В этом и задумка , там подключаются основные файлы системы .Для этого и делается одна точка входа. Не важно что после слэша в адресе будет, Вас перекинет на index.php.

Comment: Хорошо. Возможно я вас чуть позже еще спрошу :D 
Просто я как то делал index.php только с require(),но получается у меня не было перенаправления,а если я заходил на mysite.com/index.php он мне выводил просто код с этим require

Comment: @user328894 тут есть чат, не надо писать много коментов

Comment: У меня репутация не позволяет чат сделать. Может могу я вам на почту написать,описать какая у меня проблема?

Comment: @user328894 пишите, dmitriyEky@yandex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю что там у вас файлах, но:
 1. index.php - точка входа
 2. add.php - добавление
 3. sql.php - работа с бд.
В файле [2] подключаем (самый простой способ - include) файл [3].
Создаём файл [1]. Подключаем в созданном файле [2] файл. Профит

Comment: и как в эту схему укладывается файл blog.php?

Comment: О каком файле blog.php речь? 
Автор всё чётко написал: есть 2 файла - как для них сделать "точку входа".

Comment: речь идет о единой точке входа. которая является единой для многих файлов. а не для одного.

Comment: Речь идёт о нескольких файлах и точке входя для них. Именно для них, а не для многих - чёрным по белому написано это...

Comment: не следует отвечать на вопрос, если вы его не поняли

Comment: Цитирую автора: "У меня есть два файла sql.php и add.php. Как мне сделать,чтобы у меня была единая точка входа?"

Comment: В данном случае - какой вопрос, такой и ответ. Всё я правильно понял

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо,но у меня получается в файле add добавление пользователя,но в sql по мимо работы с бд есть еще отдельный код. Мне надо получается создать index.php и в нем прописать include sql.php? Только я не пойму,как тогда через него зайти?грубо говоря test1.ru/index.php?верно?